# angularjs each http function response in separate line inside HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have HTML below with ng-click running updategateways() function (this is http.post) based on check-box values. But each next response overwrites previous ones. How do I have all responses (number of response varies from one to three) in separate lines ?

```
<div class="row">
    <form name="myForm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updategateways()">Update CO Gateways</button>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="gateway.SDREPVPN"
                   ng-true-value="'SD-REPVPN'" ng-false-value=false>SD-REPVPN</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="gateway.WALREPVPN"
                   ng-true-value="'WAL-REPVPN'" ng-false-value=false>WAL-REPVPN</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="gateway.MALREPVPN"
                   ng-true-value="'MAL-REPVPN'" ng-false-value=false>MAL-REPVPN</label>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="row">
    {{response}}
</div>
```

Comment: there isn't enough information here to know what you are trying to do.  What does `updategateways()` do? what's the relationship between those checkboxes and the `{{response}}` property?  Please consider posting some JavaScript code, your expected response, and maybe a plunker.

Comment: thnx here http://plnkr.co/edit/OPUjPOGJ57t0L0iZOz1X?p=catalogue

Comment: that plunker isn't complete, it only has some javascript and the default HTML.  And based on that plunker, you are only getting one response at a time.  What are you actually *trying* to do?

Comment: Well the problem is that you overwrite the response all the time. You should add them to an array instead.

Comment: I would rather run gateways 3 times...because it takes less time

Comment: Well you are sending up to 3 post requests so you have to use a datastructure to save the responses. What do you mean when you say it takes less time? If you are affraid of performance you shouldn't really use angular imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure if I understand you correctly. But I would put the responses in an array and then use ng-repeat to show each of them. Then if there is only one response in the array only one will be shown. Something like this:

```html
<div class="row" ng-repeat="response in responses">
  {{response}}<br>
</div>
```

`updategateways()` should start by setting `$scope.responses = []`

Then in your http then clause you should do something like

```
$scope.responses.push(response)
```